# find all $(x,y,z)$ such that $27^{3x^2 + 2y}+27^{3y^2 + 2z}+27^{3z^2 + 2x}=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponentiation

> Find all ($x,y,z$) such that
> $$ 27^{3x^2 + 2y}+27^{3y^2 + 2z}+27^{3z^2 + 2x}=1$$

I am a high school student and would appreciate it if anyone could solve it using high school mathematics.

here is what I have tried till now:
$$ 3x^2 +2y < 0 $$ (this can also be said for the other 3 equation. it also means that x,y,z<0)
$$ -2y>3x^2 $$
$$ 4y^2>9x^2 $$ ( -2y and 3x^2 are both positive)
$$ 3y^2>27/4 x^2 $$
$$ -2z>3y^2>27/4 x^4 $$
$$ 4z^2 > 729/16 x^8 $$
$$ 3z^2> 2187/64 x^8 $$
$$ -128/2187<x^7 $$
$$ -2/3 < x $$
$$ -2/3< x,y,z < 0 $$

i tried this but as you can see didn't do much good

Comment: to the people who edited my question: what are the $ signs for and how did you type the powers on top like that?

Comment: i have got the answer $x=y=z=-1/3$ please show what you have tried and i will show solution

Comment: Albus, I simply wrote 3 equation 3x^2 +2y<0,  3z^2 +2x<0, 3y^2 +2z<0. I did just find a mistake in the sign though. Thanks for that. Please show the solution

Comment: please show that along with your post otherwise your question will be closed

Comment: hey hey dont close the question I am just a high school student. I will just do that, but as I said it seems to have no use

Comment: Albus, I have added what I have done. Please show the solution now.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation for info about formatting equations on this site.

Comment: PM 2Ring thanks a lot! I'll surely format future questions better

Comment: @rohangupta please see edit

Answer (score 2):

Hint:By am-gm $$1\ge3\sqrt[3]{{27}^{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)+2(x+y+z)}} = 3^{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)+2(x+y+z)+1}..(1)$$

But $$3(x^2+y^2+z^2)\ge {(x+y+z)}^2$$ when x=y=z

substituting in  (1)

$$1\ge 3^{{(x+y+z+1)}^2}$$

which is possible only when $x+y+z=-1$ and $x=y=z$

Comment: albus, could you explain where you got the first equation from? i am getting 3 instead of the 1 there.

Comment: Got your edit. Thanks a lot mate.

Comment: you can accept by clicking check mark too

Answer (score 1):

Like Albus Dumbledore, but a bit of another idea.

By AM-GM $$1=\sum_{cyc}27^{3x^2+2y}\geq3\sqrt[3]{\prod_{cyc}27^{3x^2+2y}}=3^{1+\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2+2y)}=$$
$$=3^{1+\sum\limits_{cyc}(3x^2+2x)}=3^{\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(9x^2+6x+1)}{3}}=3^{\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(3x+1)^2}{3}}\geq1,$$
which is possible only  for $$x=y=z=-\frac{1}{3}.$$